# Doubly Linked List Problems (specifically copy constructor and delete function)

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I posted this same post to Reddit, but it is not getting any comments, so I've decided to see if I can get some help here.

My current project we are given a doubly linked list .h file and a .cpp file, and we need to implement the .h in the .cpp. I am really struggling with linked lists though, I feel as though even the things i have right or kinda right are sloppy and don't fulfill the full requirements. Here is the .h file:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    string ssn;
    string name;
    Node* succ;
    Node* pred;
};

class DLL{
    private:
    Node* headPtr;
    int itemCount;

    public:
    DLL();
    DLL(DLL& n);
    virtual ~DLL();
    Node* getHeadPtr();
    int search(string ss)const;
    bool insert(string ss, string name, int & count);
    bool remove(string ss, int & count);
    int size();
    void display();
};
```

And here is the .cpp file:

```
#include "DLL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// default constructor is already implemented
// do not modify the default constructor
DLL::DLL(){
    headPtr = nullptr;
    itemCount=0;
}

// return the head pointer of the list
// it is already implemented, do not modify it
Node* DLL::getHeadPtr(){
    return headPtr;
}

// copy construct, which copies an existing list n
// the new list is a different object from n
// the new list and object n have the same contents
// Please implement it
DLL::DLL(DLL& n){
        /*Node *first = n.getHeadPtr();
    first = headPtr;
    while(headPtr->succ)
        headPtr = headPtr->succ;
    while(headPtr){
        first->succ = headPtr->succ;
        headPtr->succ = headPtr->succ->succ;
    }*/
}

// destructor
// release every node of the list
// Please implement it
DLL::~DLL(){
    Node *tmp = this->headPtr;
    Node *temp;
    while(tmp->pred)
        tmp = tmp->pred;
    while(tmp)
    {
        temp = tmp->succ;
        delete tmp;
        tmp = temp;
    }
    tmp =NULL; 
    temp = NULL;
}

// if some node has SSN matcthes string ss
// return the index value of the node
// the index value of the first node is 0, the second node is 1, etc.
// if there is node matching ss, return -1
int DLL::search(string ss)const{  
    int count = 0;
    Node *tmp = headPtr;
    while(tmp != NULL){
        count++;
    if(tmp->ssn == ss)
      return count -1;
    tmp = tmp->succ;
  }
    return NULL;
}

// insert (ss, name) to the existing list
// the SSN values are each node are organized in INCREASING order
// if there is a node matching ss value, return false; otherwise true
// else create a node with (ss, name), insert the node to the proper position
// parameter count is the counter of number of valid insertion
// when you implement this method, consider the following situations:
// 1. list is empty
// 2. node should be inserted to the beginning of the list
// 3. node should be inserted to the middle of the list
// 4. node should be inserted to the end of the list
//I use the append function, then sort afterwards
bool DLL::insert(string ss, string name, int & count){
   //Create Node
   Node *newPtr = new Node;
   newPtr->ssn = ss;
   newPtr->succ = NULL;
   //If list is empty
   if(headPtr == NULL){
        headPtr = newPtr;
        return true;
   }
   //If list is not empty
   else{
        Node* temp = headPtr;
        while(temp->succ != NULL){
            temp = temp->succ;
            itemCount++;
            count++;
        }
    temp->succ = newPtr;
    //Following part is to sort from least to greatest (based on Lab 7)
    //Store head to temp node
    temp = headPtr;
    string tempVal;
    int counter = 0;
    //Set temp to next, increase count
    while (temp){
        temp = temp->succ;
        counter++;
    }
    //Make temp head again
    temp = headPtr;
    //While less than count and has next node, check if val at temp is greater than val at next
    for (int j=0; j<count; j++){
        while (temp->succ){
            if (temp->ssn > temp->succ->ssn ){
                //Store val at temp to temp val
                tempVal = temp->ssn ;
                //Make temp's val the value at temp->next
                temp->ssn  = temp->succ->ssn;
                //Make temp->next's val, temp's old val
                temp->succ->ssn  = tempVal;
            }
            //Make temp the next value and check again
            temp = temp->succ;
        }
        //Move temp back to head    
        temp = headPtr;
    }
    return true;
   }
    return false;
}


// remove node containing ss value
// if there is no node containing ss, return false; otherwise true
// consider the following situations:
// 1. list is empty
// 2. node containing ss value is the first node
// 3. node containing ss value is in the middle of the list
// 4. node containing ss value is the last node of the list
bool DLL::remove(string ss, int & count){
    /*Node *temp = headPtr;
    while(temp){
        if(temp->ssn == ss){
            temp->pred->succ = temp->succ;
            temp->succ->pred = temp->pred;
            count++;
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp->succ;

    }
    return false;*/
}

// return the number of the nodes
// it is already implemented, do not modify it
int DLL::size(){
    return itemCount;
}

// iterate through each node
// print out SSN and memory address of each node
// do not modify this method
void DLL::display(){
    Node* temp;
    temp = headPtr;
    while (temp!= nullptr) {
        cout << temp->ssn << "\t" << temp << endl;
        temp = temp->succ;
    }
}
```

I think my search function is fine, and the functions with comments that say don't modify are made by the professor so they are fine, and the .h file is fine because it was also included. I am really struggling with the copy constructor and delete function though. The current contents of my delete function are commented out because the test.exe crashes everytime it reaches it. Then the copy constructor I am just all around lost, I've done a lot of research and read other posts, but I just can't figure it out. I have mine commented out because the program crashes everytime it reaches that function, like with the remove function. My insert function is supposed to insert everything in order and not insert it if it was already inserted, mine appends every item to the list then sorts them afterwards into order, never checking if the SSN was already in or not. It works, but obviously not fully. Any advice at all would be very helpful because as you can tell I struggling a lot with doubly linked list. Thank you in advance.

Comment: On a sidenote: I guess the comments on return values are from the professor, you should **strictly** follow those (example: Your search function is supposed to return `-1` when the value is not found, yours returns `NULL`)

Comment: @ccKep it does in fact return -1 when one isn't found, I'll be honest I'm not sure why, and I know that it shouldn't, but for some reason it does.

Comment: In that case you should debug the program flow entirely (and check that's actually the code you compiled), there is no way that function can produce a value less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem with null pointer in the constructor

```
    /*Node *first = n.getHeadPtr();
first = headPtr;
while(headPtr->succ)
```

Here `headPtr` is a nullptr and hence `headPtr->succ` raises a runtime error.

Comment: Actually in the copy constructor, `headPtr` isn't even `nullptr` - it's indeterminate since it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am kind of confused, wouldn't when the function is called, the headPtr is given when you use like DLL* newList = new DLL(oldList); I'm sorry I'm really struggling with linked lists

Comment: It's the copy constructor's job to initialize the new copy.  If you don't implement the copy ctor, the compiler will create a very basic one, but in the case of a linked list that basic one will be wrong - that's why you (the programmer) need to write the copy constructor.  The copy constructor is what the compiler will call for an expression like `new DLL(oldList)`.  So if you have a custom one (which is needed for this `DLL` class - google 'rule of three'), it has to do all the work.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I understand why the copy construct is needed, I just cannot figure out how to code one for my DLL. Do i have to use `n.getHeadPtr()` instead of just `headPtr` in that copy construct?